# Malloc implementation for prologue and epilogue in C

Tags: c, malloc

I have a task that is to write `my_free()` and `my_malloc()` function.

But how do we create epilogue and prologue to properly misalign header and footer?

Supposedly we use `sbrk()` requries `4096 bytes` from the heap.

Do I do

```
void* my_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void* heapspace = sbrk();
    heapspace += 8 // ?? Do i do this to create epilogue?


}
```

Comment: It depends on how exactly you store your bookkeeping information.  BTW pointer arithmetic on `void*` is a non-standard extension, prefer `char*` for portability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
heapspace += 8;
```

will not align anything. If you need 8 bytes alignment, and you add 8 to the unaligned address, the result will be the same unaligned.

You need to:

```
void *align(void *ptr, unsigned alignment)
{
    uintptr_t addr = (uintptr_t)ptr;

    if(addr % alignment)
    {
        addr = ((addr / alignment) + 1) * alignment;
    }
    return (void *)addr;
}
```

```
void* my_malloc(size_t size)
{
    char* heapspace = sbrk();
    heapspace += sizeof(size);   //example header size
    heapspace = align(heapspace, 8);

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether the OP is trying to align with `+= 8`, or to leave space for bookkeeping.

Comment: @Arkku same function will do. Add your header then use function to properly align for the data.

Comment: Fair enough, at the time I commented this answer only had the `align` function so it didn't really seem to answer the question. Now with the `my_malloc` it is better, although I'm still not sure what exactly the OP was asking.

Comment: @Arkku What about alignment `10` or `60`. This function is universal.  for 8 is enough to `((addr >> 3) + 1) << 3` The check is needed to not to realign aligned address

Comment: Yes, true, unneccessary confusion. =)